# discrepancy between Rømer and Fahrenheit scale

Tags: measurement

Wikipedia states that [Rømer temperature scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B8mer_scale) initially set 0 °Rø for freezing brine and 60 °Rø for boiling water. (He then slightly changed the scale, but the difference is irrelevant for my purposes).

It also [states that Fahrenheit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit#History) started with this scale *where body temperature is 22.5 °Rø*, enlarged it of a factor 4 (so that freezing water is 30 degrees and body temperature is 90 degrees) and then tweaked it so that the two values became 32 °F and 96 °F respectively; eventually some minor modification was made, and now body temperature is about 98 °F.

However this does not work: with such operations, water would be boiling over 240 °F (say, 250 °F). 212 °F would be compatible with 50 °Rø for boiling water, but I don't think that in 1701 Rømer thought to use such a value (60 °Rø made much sense, because it was easily divided in parts). Indeed, since a Rømer degree is more or less equal to 2 Celsius degrees, the value of 22.5 °Rø for the human body temperature is too low: 27.5 °Rø would make more sense.

Does anybody know what really happened?